# Relation between instruction and bytecode

Tags: jvm, bytecode

If an instruction code of 1 byte(known as bytecode) in JVM is used by a machine. How
many (instructions/bytecode) are possible?

(Not a homework question. Preparing for placement interviews.)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is actually about. From the title, you seem to be asking about how bytecodes relate to machine code instructions. But the question itself seems to be asking how many different byte code bytes there can be.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode#Instructions), there are 255 possible opcodes, because the size of an opcode is one byte (so, 256 possible values) but the value 0xCA is reserved for debugger breakpoints, leaving 255 for "real" opcodes, of which 0x00 through 0xC9, 0xFE, and 0xFF are assigned currently.